# Access Listbox to Filter another listbox

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

Is it possible to filter a listbox in a form based on another listbox in the same form. 
If so please give me a headstart.

Best regards

Comment: Search topic 'cascading combobox'. Same technique can be used with listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this for your row sources.

```
 Listbox1: SELECT id, category FROM categorytable
 Listbox2: SELECT id, subcategory FROM subcategorytable
           WHERE categoryID = Forms!NameOfForm!LListbox1
 Listbox3: SELECT id, subsubcategory FROM subsubcategorytable
           WHERE subcategoryID = Forms!NameOfForm!LListbox2
```

Also, check out this link.

http://www.blueclaw-db.com/comboboxlist/access_dependent_dropdown_list.htm